# discord.py how do i list all the channels id's?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, bots

Hello this my simple python code to get all channels in discord server .

```
# IMPORT DISCORD.PY. ALLOWS ACCESS TO DISCORD'S API.
import discord


bot = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
   text_channel_list = []
   for guild in bot.guilds:
      for channel in guild.text_channels:
         text_channel_list.append(channel)
         print(channel, guild.name)



bot.run("TOKEN")
```

the ouput of the code would be something like this :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flo1Z.png)

The name of the channel on the left  and the server name on the right

i want to get the ids of the channels next to the channel name
any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
   text_channel_list = []
   for guild in bot.guilds:
      for channel in guild.text_channels:
         text_channel_list.append(channel)
         print(channel.id, channel, guild.name)
```